# Stack overflow / endless recursion when using menukeys

Tags: recursion, stack, menukeys

since I've upgraded from TeX Live 2012 to TeX Live 2013, I have some trouble with a custom package. The package provides some commands that are intended to be used either as standalone commands or embedded within the `\keys{}` command provided by the `menukeys` package. The commands use a mechanism I've picked up somewhere to allow for an optional argument - don't know whether it's a good idea to do it that way, but it has worked so far. Now, for some reasons I don't fully understand, the system enters an endless loop until it hits the maximum stack size. Can someone please tell me what went wrong here and what I can do to prevent this?

Thanks
  Volker

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{menukeys}

% This would usually be part of my custom package...
\makeatletter
\def\foobar{\@ifnextchar[\@foobar{\@foobar[]}}
\def\@foobar[#1]#2{foo=#1, bar=#2}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
without optional argument: \foobar{FOO}

with optional argument: \foobar[BAR]{FOO} 

\keys{some key}

% the next line triggers the error: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\keys{without optional argument: \foobar{FOO}}

\keys{with optional argument: \foobar[BAR]{FOO}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\protected\def\foobar` should do. BTW: why aren't you using `\newcommand\foobar[2][]{foo=#1, bar=#2}` (or, to avoid the error you're getting here, the robust version `\newrobustcmd\foobar[2][]{foo=#1, bar=#2}` provided by the `etoolbox` package)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last version of `menukeys` introduced some `\edef` which are wrong and lead to infinite recursion whenever commands such as `\textbf` or fragile command like yours are used.

You should define `\foobar` with `\DeclareRobustCommand` anyway, if you plan to use it in the argument to `menukeys`, but the current version would fail in the same way. So ideally you should have

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\foobar{\@ifnextchar[\@foobar{\@foobar[]}}
```

and if the wrong `\edef` are changed to the correct `\protected@edef` it might work. Even better, you should use `\newcommand`:

```
\newcommand{\foobar}[2][]{foo=#1, bar=#2}
```

without using explicitly `\@ifnextchar`.

For the moment, use

```
\protected\def\foobar{\@ifnextchar[\@foobar{\@foobar[]}}
```

The suspect `\edef` commands are at lines 582, 585, 590 and 593.

---

If I change the suspect `\edef` commands in `menukeys.sty` into `\protected@edef`, the error doesn't show.

Comment: I got the same stack error with `Space bar: \keys{\makebox[2\width][c]{Space}}`. Interestingly last TeXLive-2012 version is `1.1b`, while TeXLive-2013 contains `1.1a`, although package dates are chronological (newer in TeXLive-2013). I sent a bug report to the package author.

Comment: @AlexG  `\keys{\makebox[2\width][c]{Space}}` can't work also with the patched version, because `\makebox` is fragile. And using `\protect` doesn't help either: it should be `\keys{\unexpanded{\makebox[2\width][c]{Space}}}`. I don't know why the author added that "full expansion" step to the processing of the argument.

Comment: Thank you, @egreg, for providing the workaround! The reverse versioning of the package remains mysterious.

Comment: I fixed this in version 1.2, which will be available on CTAN soon.

Comment: @egreg: I had some more bugs which seem to be fixed by replacing `\protected@edef` by a simple `\def`. Is it possible to use `\def` instead or will that cause any other problems I don’t see yet? … I’d say it’s unnecessary that the `\CurrentMenuelement` is stored as expanded macro, is it?

Comment: Unfortunatly I can’t remember or reconstruct why I introduced the `\edef`. There where `\def`s in previous versions …

Comment: @Tobi I don't know. I should go deeply in the package; for the previous problem, your usage of `\edef` was clearly improper.

Comment: Thanks. Then I’ll do some testing and switch back to `\def` – I guess …